# How to change background color of a sagetex sageblock-environment?

Tags: sagetex

When using sagetex the background of sagecommandline environments can be easily changed via lstlistings setup.

How can the background of a sageblock environment be changed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{language=Sage,
commentstyle={\ttfamily\color{green}},
keywordstyle={\ttfamily\color{blue}\bfseries},
stringstyle ={\ttfamily\color{dgraycolor}\bfseries},
tabsize = 4,
basicstyle={\small \ttfamily},
backgroundcolor= \color{orange!20},
}

\begin{document}
The following function computes the square of a number:
\begin{sageblock}
def f(x):
    return x**2
\end{sageblock}

Testing in the code gives for $x=2$ the value \sage{f(2)}.

Commandline Version:
\begin{sagecommandline}
sage: x = 2
sage: f(2)
\end{sagecommandline}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) not everyone knows what sagetex or a sageblock is, so please provide a full minimal example, otherwise it is rather hard to help

Comment: If you are unable to get help with your question, consider posting [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to achieve this. Change `colback` to the background colour you want. `tcolorbox` provide much more options (title, frame colour *etc*.), see [the documentation](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for those details.

[image: rendered pdf]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

% colback: background colour

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=orange!20, enhanced, arc=0pt, frame hidden]
\begin{sageblock}
    var('x')
    f(x) = sin(x) - 1
    g(x) = log(x)
    h(x) = diff(f(x) * g(x), x)
\end{sageblock}
\end{tcolorbox}

% verify that sageblock works

$h : \sage{h}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer is a good recommendation, but maybe you want to set `enhanced, arc=0pt, frame hidden` (requires library `skins`) to make it look like the other environment in the OP.

Comment: @TeXnician Yes, you're right, just added. I also tried to do code-highlighting with `minted`/`listings` (for `python`/`sage`) but it's far more complicated than I thought since `sage` needs to evaluate expressions in `sageblock` environment.